# Javascript: How can I force a string with decimal value to use point instead a comma?

Tags: javascript, string

I have for example:

```
 var locations = new google.maps.LatLng('@item.latitude', '@item.longitude', false);
```

@item.latitude value is for example: "43,321"

but i need it to be: 43.321

I need to force decimal separator as point not comma. How can I do this?

Comment: You should format the number before sending it to JS. That's the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
    var lat = '@item.latitude';
    var lng = '@item.longitude';
    var locations = new google.maps.LatLng(lat.replace(',','.'), lng.replace(',','.'), false);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `.replace(',', '.')`?

Comment: Thank you sir! I can finally go sleep in peace, after 5hours searching for the problem, i noticed that google map wasn't displaying markers because i had a point like this (43,123 , -7,123)! Obviously it was confused. I need to wait some time to accept answer :)

Comment: @veelen, yes! that way is correct one, thank you for that observation. I just copy paste, didn't notice that! :)